# Assembly: Help with get utf8 char function

Tags: assembly, x86

Trying to write an assembly function that returns the char at the given position in a utf-8 text.

I have tried many solutions, but I can't get it to work propperly. This is what I have so far:

```
    .globl utf8_get
    .globl _utf8_get
utf8_get:
_utf8_get:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        movl    4(%ebp), %eax
        movl    12(%ebp), %ecx

u_loop: cmpb    $0x0, (%eax)
        jz      n_fnd
        incl    %eax
        cmpl    $0x0, %ecx
        jz      fnd
        decl    %ecx
        jmp     u_loop

n_fnd:  movl    $-0x1, %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret

fnd:    movzbl  (%eax), %eax
        popl    %ebp
        ret
```

The parameters are unsigned char* and int.

But it does not return the right char.

Answer (score 0):

1. The biggest problem is that first argument is found at `8(%ebp)` - not `4(%ebp)`, which contains the return address.
2. I think you want to increment `%eax` after checking `%ecx`, not before.
3. Do you really mean UTF-8?  [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a multi-byte character encoding: the *n*<sup>th</sup> UTF-8 *character* is not necessarily the *n*<sup>th</sup> byte (a fair bit more effort is required to count characters and decode the one you're interested in).

Comment: I'm supposed to return the n'th byte, not char as I wrote... I tried to make some changes, and the result is almost right. But i get the byte before the one I wan't, it seems...

Comment: I thought the first argument was found at 4(%ebp), and the return adress at 0(%ebp) or just (%ebp)..

Comment: *On entry* to `utf8_get`, the return address is at `(%esp)` and the first argument is at `4(%esp)`.  But the prologue `pushl %ebp ; movl %esp, %ebp` is decrementing the stack pointer by 4 bytes in the push, before it is copied - so after that the old `%ebp` is at `(%ebp)`, the return address is at `4(%ebp)`, and the first argument is at `8(%ebp)`.